# Strange behaviour in my android app (Android 2.3.5) - Things get inflated wrong

Tags: android-layout, android

I've been experiencing some very strange behavours in an app I'm developing. The app is not very advanced, it stores a couple of places in a sqlite database and is displayed in listviews, on a mapview etc. So, when browsing through my app after deploying it to my phone everything works great, but after a while one listview doesn't get inflated. A scrollbar appears as if the items were there but I can't see them. I push the back button to close the app. When revisiting the app my first view, which has two buttons, gets all messed up. The buttons fill the viewport and the background disappears etc. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Anyone else facing these problems? My phone is a HTC Desire HD with Android 2.3.5

The app is pretty "layout heavy", if you know what I mean. The listview items has custom background images, I'm using custom fonts etc. But the app is running smoothly up to the point when it freaks out and displays/don't display everything wrong.

My first thought is there is some kind of memory issue, ideas?

**EDIT:** 
I believe this might have something to do with defining and using #00000000 as transparent color. Use **@android:color/transparent** instead.

**SOLUTION:** 
So after doing some testing I found that what I previously mentioned in the edit really is the cause of this problem. I had defined the transparent color in my colors.xml as #00000000. This seems to work, sometimes... And other times it grabs a drawable instead, but not a drawable that is named "transparent", it grabs ANY drawable. Weird but true.

Comment: Please post an explicit answer to your question for everybody to see you've found a fix for your issue. And thank you for investigation, it really helped us.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have now posted an answer to my question and marked it as accepted. Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing I finally found the cause of this problem. I had defined the transparent color in my colors.xml as #00000000. This seems to work, sometimes... And other times it grabs a drawable instead, but not a drawable that is named "transparent", it grabs ANY drawable. Weird but true.

So to fix this problem you should use **@android:color/transparent** instead when you want transparency on, for example, a view background.

Answer (score 0):

If there are memory errors you should be able to catch them in logcat.  You'll get "VM failed on xxxx byte allocation" messages (or the like).

Silly/stupid answer:  often when I run into layout issues within my app, it's because I needed to do a clean build after having changed my layouts.  You might want to start there.

Edit:  You might also try the emulator, and if you suspect memory issues you could start the emulator with a small heap to force the issue to occur sooner.  You can also check your heap usage in DDMS or with the Eclipse MAT to see if it's leaking.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm not getting any "VM failed on xxxx byte allocation" and I've done several cleans. I looked through the layouts and I think I might have found the problem. In my "About the app" activity I put a pretty big image inside a scrollview. The scrollview also had a background image (stupid enough) which was quite big. So I got rid of the background image, replacing it with a repeated image, removed the image inside the scrollview and the problem seems to have gone away. Very strange..

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem on Galaxy tab even with `@android:color/transparent`. Was able to fix it only by replacing `android:background="@color/transparent"` with `android:background="@null"`.